# the latest igb driver version

Tags: linux-networking, nic

I tried to make my server NIC driver update, after ethtool -i it show

[Check version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxeYC.png)

but the latest version on Intel website is lower:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13663/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-82575-6-82580-I350-and-I210-211-Based-Gigabit-Network-Connections-for-Linux-?wapkw=igb%20driver

Version 5.3.5.61

do you have info about it?

Server:
Supermicro
Centos 7.8
NIC: Intel I350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found an interesting conundrum here. Having worked as a contractor for the networking group at Intel, I can attest that the latest version of its adapter drivers are uploaded to its website; Intel does not give special access to the latest version to any vendor first. This said, the latest version on the Intel website is not 5.4.0-k as you write (actually 5.3.6; 5.3.5.61 is the previous release) which was bundled in Centos 7.8.

My guess is that Red Hat (who created the code Centos is based on) decided to assign a new version number to the driver code for some reason. The usual reason is that they modified the code. (I did a quick look through a system with CentOS 7.8, but failed to find any documentation explaining why the version of igb was changed.)

As a final note, the -k at the end of the version number shows this is the version included in the base package, & not one later downloaded & compiled -- a useful bit of information for troubleshooting driver problems.

Comment: is it safe to download and compile the Igb listed on Intel? because i am not sure if the version included in Centos as 5.4 is up-to-date.

Comment: You don't seem to be up to date with CentOS 7.8. I also use it, I also use igb and my version is 5.6.0-k. Please make sure you have an up to date kernel.

Comment: Yes it is safe to compile the driver from the Intel website. One additional thought: check the date of your igb driver: the source on the Intel website should be more recent than what comes with CentOS.